# How are usually denoted functions whose derivative is absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, notation, terminology, absolute-continuity

Given a real interval $I$, are there standard name and notation for the vector space
$\{f\in C^1(I)\,:\,f'\,\mathrm{is}\,\mathrm{absolutely}\,\mathrm{continuous}\}$?

I would guess $C^1_{a.c.}$ but I'm not sure if it is a widely used notation or if it requires to be defined explicitely.

And what about the spaces $\{f\in C^n(I)\,:\,f^{(n)}\,\mathrm{is}\,\mathrm{absolutely}\,\mathrm{continuous}\}$?

Comment: I think that this space is the same as the Sobolev space $W^{2,1}(I)$. This is the space of functions whose weak derivatives are in $L^1$ up to the second order.

Comment: I've seen $\operatorname{AC}^1(I)$ (and generally $\operatorname{AC}^n(I)$) used. But it's probably not usual enough to use without defining the notation.